# @Published var item: any? cast to concrete type and preserve binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Note to reader: This was a dumb mistake on my part... I was using `@Binding` in my subview when I should have used `@ObservedObject`. This lead me to think I needed to cast to `Binding<ConcreteModel>`..

I have a published var of type `Any?`, I would like to cast it and pass it to a `View` expecting `Binding<ConcreteModel>`... Is this supported?

Problem with my casting?

```
// This cast doesn't seem to be working...
if let concreteModel = viewModel.item as? Binding<ConcreteModel> {}
```

I'm not having success with this:

```
class ConcreteModel {
    public var count = 0
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item: Any?

    init() { item = ConcreteModel() }
}

// SwiftUI
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        // This cast doesn't seem to be working...
        if let concreteModel = viewModel.item as? Binding<ConcreteModel> {
            MySecondView(concreteModel: concreteModel)
        }   
    }
}

struct MySecondView: View {
    @Binding var concreteModel: ConcreteModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(concreteModel.count)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using generics?  For example ...

```swift
protocol Initializable {
  init()
}

class ConcreteModel: Initializable {
  public var count = 0
  required init() {}
}

class MyViewModel<T>: ObservableObject where T: Initializable {
  @Published var item: T?

  init() { item = T() }
}

struct MyView: View {
   @ObservedObject public var viewModel = MyViewModel<ConcreteModel>()

    var body: some View {        
       MySecondView(concreteModel: $viewModel.item)  
    }
}

struct MySecondView: View {
    @Binding var concreteModel: ConcreteModel?

    var body: some View {
        if let concreteModel = concreteModel {
           Text("\(concreteModel.count)")
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics is the way to go here. You cannot assign a type of `Any?` and then change its type. That is, for as far as I know, not really supported. Using generics solves this because the type you use is the same as the generic type.

Comment: Totally agree.. I was mistaken with what I had going on in my code.. Read what I replied with to Aspari

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is *a* solution:

```
// SwiftUI
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        
        // get concrete type
        if var concreteModel = viewModel.item as? ConcreteModel {
            // create new binding
            let binding = Binding<ConcreteModel>(get: {
                concreteModel
            }, set: {
                concreteModel = $0
            })
            // pass through new binding
            MySecondView(concreteModel: binding)
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You bound to local stack variable, which is senseless, and what's the reason to bind to reference type instance if can just pass it as is, by reference.

Comment: @Asperi you are right.. I looked closer at my code... Where I should have used `@ObservedObject` in the subview I was using `@Binding` leading me to thing I had to cast to it.. You've help me lots. Thanks!